# Should SyncAdapter.onPerformSync be blocking?

Tags: java, android

I am aware that SyncAdapters are executed on a different thread than the main thread but are there any guidelines on how to design the execution?
The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) about it only state that I need to implement the logic by myself, fine but any details?

Any advices on how to use `SyncResult`?

Should `onPerformSync` actually be a *blocking* call or rather not? For instance if I need to execute some async tasks like fetching data from a server, *should* I or *must I not* block `onPerformSync`?

Can I prevent a re-scheduling of the sync with `SyncResult` in a reliable way instead of using [delayUntil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncResult.html#delayUntil)?

Or should I entirely guard the multi-threading critical parts of `onPerformSync` with a synchronized object by myself because concurrent or even re-entrant execution can happen at any time?

Comment: All of the sync adapter development I have seen uses blocking calls in the onPerformSync. You should make your calls blocking. More information is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424561/regulate-network-calls-in-syncadapter-onperformsync

Comment: You can prevent the re sceduling if the sync based on your sync result.. i.e **you can can store a version to your local persistant database..if the version is less that the API version** then you should perform the sync` i.e its depending on the last sync result..

Comment: like if the user updates any of the details ..you can perform sync then ....it depends upon your application functions..

Comment: @dazza5000 "All of the sync adapter development I have seen" -> have you seen more than the single retrofit link at SO you provided? :) I personally haven't so it is currently the only implementation known to me

Comment: Yes - syncadapter for years